# Mountain bike tyres, could somebody explain what the markings mean?

Tags: mountain-bike

I have just bought new all terrain mountain bike tyres. On the tyre wall it says: inflate to 280kpa (40 psi), MAX LOAD 75KG (165 LBS).

Could somebody explain, and could somebody tell me what my maximum and what my minimum tyre pressure would be.

Comment: Check the numbers. I think you mean __70__ kg (approx 154lbs)

Comment: For MTB usage, 40psi is way too high for most people. It will depend on your weight, bike, and riding style.

Answer (score 1):

Max load is how much mass you can load the tires with. I.e. the mass of the rider plus mass of the bike plus the mass of any accessories.

The load is *approximately* split equally between the two wheels so your total load mass would be 140kg (~308lbs).

Quality tires would usually give you a max and min inflation pressure. You can probably take the 280kpa as a maximum value.

Comment: As a side note the max load is generally at the max inflation. The max load will go down with lower tire pressure.

Comment: In a non-mountainous situation, I would imagine you could carry more mass. The dynamic loading would be much less.